# SQLite if condition - near "CASE": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, if-statement

I keep getting this error for my sqlite **if-condition** query below,

```
SELECT *
FROM speckdata AS s

LEFT JOIN weatherunderground AS w 
ON s.wid_timestamp = w.wid_timestamp

LEFT JOIN nodes AS n 
ON n.nid = s.nid
AND n.datatype = 'speck'

WHERE DATE(localdate) BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2015-05-12'
AND n.nid = '9'

CASE WHEN 'polar plot' != NULL THEN w.wspdi != '-9999' ELSE w.wspdi != NULL END
```

Error,

> near "CASE": syntax error ] Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>   Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression has nothing to do with the rest of the statement --- it isn't connected in any way. It looks like you're trying to add a condition to the `WHERE` clause, but you don't have an `AND` or `OR` there. So, you get a syntax error because you have a query followed by a random unconnected expression.